# Angular 2 and Semantic JS and jQuery. Теряется объект?

Tags: angular2

В Angular 2 очень плохо разбираюсь. Сложно поставить правильно вопрос. Если что не так, прошу уточнить в комментариях.

Суть проблемы вот в чем. Есть Semantic UI, нахожу модальное окно и вызываю его...

```
jQuery(this.elementRef.nativeElement).find('.ui.basic.modal#enter-modal').modal('show');
```

Окно отображается. Когда закрываю, второй раз открыть модальное окно я не могу. Я подозреваю, что после закрытия Angular 2 удаляет его из DOM дерева. Как сделать так, что бы модальное окно можно было открыть два и более раз?

Comment: Не использовать jQuery для манипуляции с DOM. Для чего вам ангуляр вообще в проекте нужен?

Comment: @VladimirGamalian jQuery вполне себе можно использовать вместе с Angular2. Как вы, например, сделаете DragnDrop или хотя бы тоже модальное окно без манипуляций с DOM? А если есть манипуляции с DOM то можно и jQuery использовать. Другое дело что надо все делать с умом.

Comment: Возможно что и удаляет его, сделайте минимальный пример с ошибкой чтобы понять как у вас устроено. Тода проще будет найти ошибку.